# mysql friend table estimated limit

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a simple social networking friend type innodb table:

```
|id - int auto inc PK
|uid - int indexed
|fid  - int indexed
```

Besides disk/memory usage, is there a way to know approximately how many friends/rows per user before it starts affecting performance?
I'm looking for a algorithm, rule of thumb, etc. ? The only thing I can think of is load testing it with X rows but I'm hoping there is a much better/scientific way

Comment: There isn't a scientific way to exactly pinpoint how many rows. There's only WHEN performance will start to drop. And it will start once you exceed `innodb_buffer_pool` amount of memory used by InnoDB to have working data-set in the memory, because it'll start using HDD at that point. Now, you can do a test to see how much memory is occupied when you have 1M rows in that table and try to estimate from there.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by affecting performance? Actually every row is affecting performance because it is constantly a little slower.

When you make proper use of indexes, a good databaseplan and optimised query's you are able to grow a lot before a visitor is going to notice anything.

And by a lot I actually mean A LOT. How much is depended on your server-speed, Query quality and and so much more that a real calculation will be very difficult to make, if not impossible.

Just concentrate on optimised database and query's.

Comment: So indexes are magic unicorns that make db go fast and they don't use resources? There's a limit that can easily be calculated. Once buffer pool is full, hdd is being hit. That's the breaking point. There are no indexes in this world that will make it go fast if the reads are done from disk (since mechanical drives are super slow, SSDs are far better). Your answer is sadly misleading, I don't agree with it, however I won't downvote.

Comment: What I meant to say with my answer is that without knowing what query's and indexes the user is using there is no way of telling when your so called breaking point is reached. You can make a table with 5 rows very slow when you use the wrong query.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I see 1 table with 3 fields and 3 indexes. It's easy enough to calculate how much space that table will occupy when there's 1 million records in it. Assuming that there are no *omgwtf* queries, and that specified indexes are being used correctly - yes, one can *measure* where the breaking point might be.

Comment: Yeah, but calculating the space a table occupy's says nothing about the speed of his query's and when a user is going to notice a difference. A SELECT * FROM Users is a lot faster then SELECT (CASE...) FROM Users INNER JOIN (...) .... So without knowing how and what he is going to do with this table there is no way to say when it is affecting performance.

Comment: Ok so after I test few queries with 1mil rows and assume performance is still good, how would i find out a # per each user from that? is there a difference between 1 uid having 100 fid or 1000 uid having 1 fid from the db's point of view? and N.B. please tell me how? and if i converted to memory (since its all ints) would be faster?

Comment: Luc Prevoo actually I will have one strange query
like a reverse lookup SELECT id FROM fid IN() ... and filled with ints..but assuming i will not use more then 50 per query

Comment: just test it, that is the only advice I can give you. When you hit a query that is very slow, post it on stackoverflow, maybe we can speed it up for you :)

Comment: My original question specifically stated not blindly testing and NB had an answer/algorithm but did not answer

Comment: @user2339423 - why do you need a number per user? Assuming that 1 user can have 1000 friends, then you reach a number of 1000 users before exceeding 1M rows which still performed good - which is ok. I wouldn't limit myself or build a feature around how many friends will cause the table to start affecting performance. That's something you'll never be able to extrapolate. What you can do is check how many records you can insert into a table before it starts using HDD for calculations / joins.

Comment: ahh i see...thanks, how can i check that? just run my query and if it takes longer then 1-2 seconds assume it uses hdd?